# issues in displaying map data with map integration

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

My issue is when i am running the app it shows Google icon in left corner in app and little grey colour in activity but it does not show google map.can any one solve this problem with intilligence i refer lot of websites ?

```
 public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements  OnMapReadyCallback {
 GoogleMap mMap;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
}
```

Manifest file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.anilkumar.mapsactivity">
<permission android:name="com.example.anilkumar.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission     android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.anilkumar.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have enabled location permission if you are testing on marshmallow devices
2. Using the correct google maps api key, and setting enabled google maps api in your console
3. Still getting errors follow these tutorials
   [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html), [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm), [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/), [this](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-google-maps-tutorial-google-maps-android-api/), [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-google-maps-for-android-basics--cms-24635)
   Hope it helps you